# How to search and replace strings with SQL

Tags: php, mysql

so i´ve change my mind....

i´ve enter around 1200 records into a text type field... like so:

```
this is <span class="italic">the</span> flower<br />
that speaks the mind<br />
bla bla bla<br />
```

If you notice, i've inserted a class named **italic**... well that is my mistake...
I need to loop all of the 1200 records and replace the class **italic** with **espWord**

How do i achieve that ?

```
SELECT lyrics.lyrics_id, lyrics.lyrics
FROM lyrics
WHERE ?????

replace italic with espWord
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE lyrics set lyrics.lyrics = replace(lyrics.lyrics, 'italic', 'espWord');

I would never personally have a table name with a field of the same name; to great a potential for confusion.

Comment: Note that this will replace all "italic" found in the whole text.

Comment: lets hope not to may people sing of font styles :-)

Comment: wow! that was fast... tried it and it works... 1200 records updated in 0.016 seconds !!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not well versed enough with MySql to say if there's a complete MySql solution, but You could try selecting the data like

```
SELECT SELECT lyrics.lyrics_id, lyrics.lyrics
FROM lyrics
WHERE `field` LIKE '%<span class=\"italics\">%'
```

Then use a program like preg_replace or sed to replace the value and update the field.  I haven't used both in long enough that I can't think of the expression off the top of my head.

Hope this helps.